# Bash script hangs if I interrupt it

Tags: linux, bash

For example there are

```
ps -ax
PID TTY Stat Time Command

1    ? Ss  0:00 /sbin/init

. 
.
.

1564 ? Sl 0:00 usr/bin/xyz

1569 ? Sl 0:00 gnome-terminal

.
.
1730 ? sl 0:00 gcaltool
1759 ? sl 0:00 firefox
```

I have to interrupt the process 1564

```
1564 ? Sl 0:00 usr/bin/xyz

1569 ? Sl 0:00 gnome-terminal
```

The terminal gets hanged if I interrupt the process PID 1564. I think it hangs because I am interrupting the terminal process. Is there any other way as I have to strace the process

```
process PID 1730,
process PID 1759,
```

which were generated at the last?
Any way to bypass the strace and interrupt of the terminal process?

Comment: Are you running this on the console or an X terminal emulator? And when you say that you interrupt the process, how are you doing this?

Comment: Also, "I think it hangs because I am interrupting the terminal process." Well, look and see. I can, for instance, `pgrep xfce4-terminal`, and it outputs `2109`. Does something similar to that give you `1569`?

Comment: Why did you delete the old question? If you had a question about the answer you're now using you should have asked in comments or at least accepted it and posted a new question then.

Comment: I m running it on the X terminal emulator and I am using ctrl+c to interrupt one process and go to the next process

Comment: @ BroSlow Sorry about that

Comment: @user3520466 Still awaiting your answer on my second comment.

Comment: yes it is a terminal process @Two-Bit Alchemist

Comment: you know about `$$` and `$PPID`? maybe they can help? Good luck.

Comment: per your question that you just deleted. I just noticed that your processing a loop using $1, but never `shift` the list, to get a new argument. Is your problem that you just getting an `strace` for only 1 process? Also are you sure that `-o log.txt` will accept input as if it was created by the shell append `>>`? I would think 1 `strace` produces 1 log file per run. Finally, to confuse things further, each `strace` you start up will create a new PID in the `ps` results list. I think we need to know a little bit about what you hope to accomplish with this. Seems overly ambitious. Good luck.